# What is BENCHMARK(count, expr)?

Tags: mysql, sql

I search and i find that it is used for time delay sql injection vulnerabilty. But what the means of the **count and expr**.

Why they are here?

What is the use of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "count" means how many times do you want the Query(expr) execute
2. It's a way to train your sql performance...

when you execute a Query,maybe it spent 0.0005 sec.

but if you use the BENCHMARK(10000, Query), it will execute the Query 10000 times and spend 5 sec or more(or less).

PS. The time spend calculate depend on the client's side, not on server side.

Comment: But what the mean of the **expr**? is it means to a querry

Comment: Is it means to a query? Yes

Comment: Can any one please show me some example of the query use in it.